# Why bootstrap datatable css file does not load

Tags: heroku, bootstrap-4, datatables

i have simple python/django app with bootstrap datatable which works fine in localhost. But not in heroku. the css file does load correctly it seems. What is the problem?

Can anyone help me fix this issue pls?

Link : https://aosoc.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Herokuapp works with `HTTPS` by default. You `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/` are trying to include a `CDN` with `HTTP`. [This behavior is blocked by browsers by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content).

[image]

**Please try replacing it with the links below.**

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
```

Comment: Thanx. Great help. Works fine.